# Asterisk Ivr menu mysql build

Tags: mysql, voip, asterisk

I would like to implement an IVR menu to see if the call comes in and announces a text waiting 6 numbers.
Then the number 6 is controlled by a MySQL database. If "Active" or "Valid" the status will be forwarded to an extension,
If you do not, or can not find it send the voicemail line. Asterisk in version 1.8.

```
Mysql
===========================
|     code   |   status    |
|------------|-------------|
|  445252    |   Active    |
|  555355    |    Valid    |
|  545422    |   Active    |
|  155222    |   Expired   |
============================
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by dialplan

Functions used can be

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+realtime

Also you can read this

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+tips+ivr+menu

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Dialplan+Patterns